# Is doom shroom worth its price?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

I happen to be wondering if doom shroom is worth its sun cost. It is a (fairly) cheap plant for its high damage and range but the crater is starting to concern me. You cannot plant in it for 3 whole minutes. Are they worth their sun cost?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To offer a counter-perspective; it can be, depending on the situation.

Yes, during the main campaign, not really. You may find it useful in some levels, simply due to its cheap cost and effectiveness, but after a while it doesn't really pay off as you find other options, like the Cherry Bomb, or the Jalapeño, etc.

***However...*** The Doom Shroom can act as a "back-up" Cherry Bomb, in tight situations. For example, on some survival levels you may get Gargantuar Zombies, *and* Enraged Gargantuar Zombies (sometimes even 2 waves in a row), which can *really* put pressure on your defenses. In those situations having a backup option to deal high damage in a 3x3 area *definitely* pays off, and dealing with an unusable square or two instead of having to rebuild half your defenses definitely makes them worthwhile.

Comment: I'm gonna agree with this answer. Its really a 'last-resort' type of unit. If you know the current wave will do a lot more damage than the doom shroom, plant one so you can get rid of that bad wave. But do not plant one if that wave is no danger at all.

Comment: Just a little something, in versus mode, the doom shroom is like way too powerful. After sudden death, you can doom all the zombies on screen every 20 seconds. Who cares about a crater when you can amass such powerful weapons?

Answer (score 3):

Really, if I had to choose (1 slot, a different plant, or Doom Shroom) I would pick the other plant.⠀

The Doom shroom has a wide area of effect, but leaves a crater on the ground for 3 minutes. That could really limit your defense late-game. Plus, the cooldown is very long, even with the Imitater.

All in all, it is mostly a better option to choose a different plant over Doom-Shroom.

Answer (score 1):

I generally don’t use doom shroom, it’s not a bad plant but there are tons of other good plants. The disadvantages of doom shroom in my opinion make it not worth its main effect.